# Android - Prevent multiple line breaks in the text of a switch

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I would like to use a constraint layout and a flow in order to display several switches side by side and automatically get a line break in case of missing place, depending on the size of the device.

That works with multiple TextView but that doesn't with switches. In case of missing place, the text of the switch is displayed on multiple lines (for example one character per line) if there is a little place, or it is not displayed if there is no place.

So, how to prevent line breaks in the text of a switch ? And how to constraint the switch?